# Given a string,s ,split the string into tokens

Tags: java, string

I define a token to be one or more consecutive English alphabetic letters. Then, print the number of tokens, followed by each token on a new line.String 's' is composed of English alphabetic letters, blank spaces, and any of the following characters: !,?._'@
Here what I'm doing.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class apples {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         String s = scan.nextLine();
         scan.close();

            String[] splitString = (s.split("[\\s!,?._'@]+"));
            System.out.println(splitString.length);
            for (String string : splitString) {
                System.out.println(string);
              }
}
}
```

When I input a string starting with any of those above characters then my code is counting the character and while printing it gives a empty space, like this.

```
    @dsd sd.sf 
    4

    dsd
    sd
    sf
```

What I'm expecting is this.

```
    @dsd sd.sf 
    3
    dsd
    sd
    sf
```

Please Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no text before the first separator so you get an empty string.  I suggest you ignore the first empty string. You could also add a separator at the start so you know there is one you can always ignore. e.g.

```
String[] split = ("@"+s).split("\\W+"); 
int words = split.length - 1;
```

or you can truncate leading non letters

```
String[] split = s.replaceAll("^\\W+", "").split("\\W+");
```

Comment: I tried your solution, the token count is now correct but while printing the token I'm still getting that empty string in my output. BTW how do I ignore the first empty string and for your solution what if the input is a normal string like "Hi what is your name".

Comment: @Gabbar to ignore the first String, you skip it e.g. instead of looping from 0, loop from 1. Or you could use my second suggestion.

Comment: thanks for your solution. It solved most of my problem but when I input nothing or just the non-alphanumeric characters then also I am getting the token count 1 instead of 0. Instead I used the java.util.StringTokenizer class and it worked perfectly. But if you have any other solution which doesn't involve the use of StringTokenizer then please tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (!scan.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(0);
        }
        else
        {
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            scan.close();
            s=s.replaceAll("^\\W+", "");  
            String[] words = s.split("[\\s',!?._@]+");

            int len=words.length;
            System.out.println(len);

                for(String i:words)
                {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }

        }
    }
}
```